# Searching Text file for lines of characters

Tags: python

I need to write a code where my code searches through the a play, then the user can specify which Act, Scene, and Character they want to see the lines of in the entire play (So they can specify first act, second scene, character X, and the code prints out the lines specified by the user). I need to use two different dictionaries. I understand my first dictionary needs to have a key of the act and value of the second dictionary, and my second dictionary needs key-value pair of Scene-character, then I need to print off the lines. This is what I have so far

```
Dict = {}
with open ('play.txt','r') as inFile:
    for lines in inFile:
        A= lines.strip()
        if b.starts with ('ACT'):
           Dict[]

for values in sorted (Dict):
    Dict1 = {}
    

Act = input('Which act do you want to learn about?')
Scene = input ('Which scene do you want to see within this act?')
Character = input('Which character do you want to see the lines of?')

for items in Dict:
    if act in Dict:
        if scene in Dict1:
            if character in Dict1:
                print ()
```

I have bits and pieces of what I need, but it isn't quite coming together, suggestions? Sorry I am new to programming and might be off with my terminology, but I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to programming! What you need to do when approaching a problem is to break down the problem into as many, small steps as you can. Then you can implement/test each part separately. For the steps, let's see:

- You want to break down the play into acts
- You want to break down each act into scenes
- You want to break down each scene by character dialogue

Then you need to think about each of the steps, like what denotes each act, scene, character? How will you store each act and what type of information does each act need? The same goes for scenes and dialogue. Then you can think about what types of data structures you need to do that, like dictionaries or lists.